# flip book (pdf/www version)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've done a catalogue in photoshop. I am looking for way to change it to flip book (pdf/www version). There are many such tools on the market but they are expensive. Maybe there is a free way? I have the creative cloud licence.
Thanks for help.

Comment: As far as I know, to make a flip book you just create an ordinary single page pdf and the flip book effect is created with some code on a web site. It's not a file format you can save in and send to people. Where/how specifically do you want to display your catalog? This question might be more about coding than about graphic design.

Comment: Thanks for comment Wolff. I need put it on webpage. I think I looking a tool which convert ordinary single page pdf (like you said) to html5. I wonder if Adobe Reader pro can do it. Maybe someone has experience?

Comment: You say "a webpage". Is it your *own* site where you manage the code yourself?

Comment: Yes, I bought a some hosting space and domain and I created easy web page. I am lookin for something which convert my png files to flip book. Result in html5 would be the best.